# If $x-\sqrt{\frac7x}=8$, find $x-\sqrt{7x}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> If $x-\sqrt{\frac7x}=8$, find $x-\sqrt{7x}$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Okay,thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:   moving the radical to one side and squaring gives $\,x^3-16 x^2 + 64 x - 7 = 0\,$. The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) finds the root $\,x=7\,$, which gives the factorization $\,(x-7)(x^2 - 9x + 1)=0\,$. But $\,x=7\,$ is not a root of the original equation, so that one must be a root of $\,x^2-9x+1=0\,$, whose roots are both real and positive.

Then $\,x - \sqrt{7x}=x\left(1-\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{x}}\right)=x\big(1-(x-8)\big)=x(9-x)=\ldots\,$